# Java application is blocking in console

Tags: java

i wrote a java application which has several classes.

One class is a Thread with that method:

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.next();
    coins = Double.valueOf(input);
    maximumPrice = Double.valueOf(scanner.next());
    while (!isInterrupted()) {
        input = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("stop".equals(input) || "sell".equals(input) || "panic".equals(input)) {
            System.out.println("here");
            commandRelevant = true;
            commandValue = input;
            interrupt();
        }
        if (input.contains("override")) {
            commandRelevant = true;
            if (input.contains("positive")) {
                commandValue = "positive";
            } else if (input.contains("negative")) {
                commandValue = "negative";
            } else if (input.contains("activate")) {
                commandValue = "activate";
            } else if (input.contains("unpredictable")) {
                commandValue = "unpredictable";
            } else {
                commandValue = "neutral";
            }
        }
        if (input.contains("setPrice")) {
            commandRelevant = true;
            commandValue = input;
        }
    }
}
```

My whole program actually runs independently to that class. Only one class access this thread class with a getter

```
 public boolean commandRelevant() {
    return commandRelevant;
}
```

**My problem is:**

When I run this application in my IDE, everythings work fine for hours. No Input, nothing will be blocked. An if I give an input, my application does what it should.

But as soon as I put my code in a jar file, upload it to the server, running 
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

my application is running for lets say 30 minutes and then it suddenly starts to block **without** any input.
When I click the command line and enter for example just a space my application cotinues suddenly...then block again after a second until I press space or another key again in the command line. It is like bewitched.

Does someone here please have an idea what could be the problem here?
Is that a VM problem? I just start my programm with java -jar application.jar

Comment: Could be a cursed VM. @Tom that only blocks the separate thread, as it's supposed to. He's worried about his whole application (other threads) blocking (for which we don't see the code).

Comment: @Kayaman Oh ok, missed that his whole app blocks, instead of the thread only. Thanks.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the problem is with this particular code. You could use VisualVM to connect to the running application on the server and see what's going on when it starts to behave weirdly. You could also show the other code, the one that you see starting to "block".

Comment: unfortunately there are a lot of classes and code. Moreover I tested it without the input thread class and then it worked fine.
I'll try it with VisualVM and update as soon as i found the bug. If someone else has another idea you are welcome.

Comment: I found the problem. It is probably a "noob" problem, i didn't know that. As soon as i click into the console window with my mouse. The program stops. When I maximazie or minimize the window the program continues. I use windows 10 and cmd.exe as a command line. How is that problem called?

Comment: I had behaviour like that only in Windows cmd.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could solve it. ALT + Space in the cmd.exe ...then settings and deactivate easy edit mode!